# How to get rid of StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while converting String to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, java-8, localdatetime

While converting from String to LocalDateTime StringIndexOutOfBoundsException occured.

```
   String date = "2020-10-20 04:51:54";
   LocalDateTime dateTime = this.convertToLocalDate(date);
    public LocalDateTime convertToLocalDate(String datStr) {
        if ( datStr != null ) {
            datStr = (String) datStr.subSequence(0, datStr.lastIndexOf("+"));
        } else {
            return LocalDateTime.now();
        }

        return LocalDateTime.parse(datStr, dateFormatter);
    }
```

Getting Indexof as -1.

Comment: There's no `+` in your `date` thus returning the `-1` - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: And what is you expected? Chech in docs what lastIndexOf returns when cannot find

Comment: the scenario is im getting the string from db , which is they are converting Date into String.

Answer (score 1):

Your string declared as date does not contain a plus sign.

The java documentation says following for the return value of String.lastIndex:

```
the index of the last occurrence of the specified substring, or -1 if there is no such occurrence.
```

Comment: I'm getting this String from db. How can i convert it into LocalDateTime

Comment: Thanks for help.this issue was caused by a typo.